# Event viewer shows .NET runtime error

Tags: .net-framework, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

while testing our main software (written in C++), the app crashed.

Looking at the event viewer, a .NET Runtime error occured at the crashing time. The .NET Runtime error may be from a Visual C++ (Managed C++) bridge we use to implement some C# assembly functionalities.

Now, the error says the following:

```
Application: OurProduct.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319 (we are using .NET Framework 4.0 in C++/CLI)
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exceptioninformation: Exceptioncode c0000005, Exceptionaddress 000000006315BFE3
Stack:
EventId: 1026
```

I am not sure how to deal with this issue. It doesn't give me any information. Any help?

Comment: Unless there is a stack trace, the information is not helpful. Use the debugger or add logging if that doesn’t work out.

Comment: That was what I thought. Thanks a lot @Daniel B

Comment: @DanielB one question though. Since I receiver a .NET Exception, does this mean it has to be a error that occurred in my C++/CLI layer?

Comment: I think it could also be something like a SEH exception that occurred in code called from .NET. I’m not very familiar with C++/CLI unfortunately.